# Attribute tag will not work in css as one of my selectors

Tags: css-selectors

Is there any reason that  this attribute tag a[h2]{color:orange;} wont work in css? I Cant seem to get the attribute tag to work for any elements.

Comment: What should `a[h2]` do? Is your HTML markup `<a h2="whatever">...</a>`? If not, you have bad rule in CSS.

Comment: If you can share the relevant HTML, and let us know which element you want to select, we'll be able to provide better answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
a[h2] {
    color:orange;
}
```

Means that all `<a>` tags that have an attribute called `h2` will be coloured orange; i.e. `<a h2="whatever">hello, world!</a>`.

This is probably not what you want, both because this would be invalid HTML (`h2` is not an attribute of `<a>`, and custom attributes are only allowed if they start with `data-`), but also because I am assuming that you want to target `<h2>` tags that are *inside* of your `<a>` tags.

To that, use the following code:

```
a h2 {
    color:orange;
}
```

That will colour all `<h2>` tags inside of `<a>` tags orange.

Read more about CSS Selectors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

Answer (score 0):

Did you make a reference in the html page to your stylesheet? 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">`
If this is done, check whether the  element has an h2 attribute. Something like `<a h2="value">`